# Updating ListView by changed RealmList<>

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, realm

Suppose this data model based on [realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/):

```
public class JournalEntry : RealmObject {
        ...
}

public class JournalOwner : RealmObject {
        ...
        public RealmList<JournalEntry> Entries { get; } 
}
```

I have a **JournalEntriesPage**, which show a **ListView** of all **JournalEntry** items of a **JournalOwner**.

Inside the corresponding view model, I pass the **JournalOwner** to the constructor and assign the **JournalOwner.Entries** to the property **Entries**.

```
public class JournalEntriesViewModel {

        private Realm _realm;

    private JournalOwner _owner;
    public RealmList<JournalEntry> Entries { 
        get { return _owner.Entries; }
    }
    ....
    public JournalEntriesViewModel( JournalOwner owner ) {

        _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        _owner = owner;

        AddEntryCommand = new Command(AddEntry);
        DeleteEntryCommand = new Command<JournalEntry>(DeleteEntry);

    }
```

If I add a **JournalEntry** via the UI, it gets created but does not appear in the **ListView**.

If I move up the Navigation (to **JournalOwner**) and then down to the entries of the owner, the **ListView** shows the newly created **JournalEntry**.

Somehow, the **ListView** of **JournalEntry**s does not know about the newly created JournalEntry.

The **JournalEntriesPage** binds the ListView like so:

```
<ListView 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" 
   x:Name="EntriesListView" 
   ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"     
   ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" >
```

**How Do I mange the ListView show newly created entries immediately?**

I feel, that I somehow need to inform observers (?) of Entries that its value changed.

In a corresponding situation, changes to the entries of

```
Owners = _realm.All<JournalOwner>();
```

do force the corresponding ListView to change immediately.

Comment: RealmList needs to implement INotifyCollection changed in order for the ListView to be notified of updates.

Comment: @Jason If in another class, changes to _realm.All<JournalOwner>() do get reflected in the ListView, doesn't RealmList implement INotifyCollection?

Comment: I haven't done any hands on with Realm yet so I can't say for sure

Comment: Do changes to realm.All<JournalOwner>() really reflect the changes or is the list getting refreshed in the life cycle methods from page change? I think your thought that observers need to be notified and @Jason 's answer are spot on.

Comment: @ClintLandry Ah, I see. And I don't know. Unfortunately, I'm new to all that. I'll try to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RealmList<T>` does not implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` as @Jason has pointed out and so it cannot notify the ListView of changes. Your best bet would be to manually reload the data in the ListView.

`RealmResults<T>` on the other hand does implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` (though the API around that [will soon change slightly](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/pull/547)). That's why a ListView bound to `_realm.All<JournalOwner>()` updates according to changes in the database.

The underlying infrastructure for observable lists is [there](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/wrappers/src/object-store/src/impl/list_notifier.hpp), it's just a matter of time before it's exposed at the C#-level.

Comment: That's what I'm in search. Inside the JournalEntryDetailsPage. How do I reload the data in the ListView? Or may I use another type as ListView's binding source? But which type?

Comment: I know it might sound silly, but implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `JournalEntriesViewModel` and raising the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Entries` property should force the ListView to rebind.